# What is the best way to handle authorization when users can have multiple roles in dotnet Core (implementation without Identity Server)

Tags: .net, authentication, .net-core, oauth-2.0, user-roles

I'm trying to create an Authentication/Authorization project and requirements are the users to have multiple roles in the application and based on the roles each method can be authorised. A user can have multiple roles and we are not supposed to use Identity Server, but rather do it from Dotnet core libraries. (Would be doing token bases authentication and using JwtBearer library)

The problem is with creating a user with multiple roles and then authorizing methods based on the role. It seems impossible to do via Dotnet core and I'm struggling since past few days. None of the microsoft references explain doing this.

Comment: im sure, that you should read more about JwtBearer + scopes + claims.
Scopes are more a group of claims, custom claims could be permissions. Using both can be a way to handle roles

Answer (score 1):

You can create a User table that manages users, a Role table that manages roles and a USER ROLE table that manages which user has which role.

You can manage multiple roles by defining policy:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowedAdminAndMod", policy =>
        policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin", "Moderator")); 
});
```

Usage:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize("AllowedAdminAndMod")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
{
    var data = await Mediator.Send(new GetAllCategoriesQuerie());
    var result = new SuccessDataResult<List<CategoryDto>>(data);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

If you are using JWT this method will work for you. If you want to authorize in Service instead of Controller, you can do it using Aspect Oriented Programming(AOP).